# Django form validation failing for formset with choicefield

Tags: django, formset

My formset consists of choice field with initial data populated from Views.py, Formset is generated properly with initial data but when I submit the form the form.is_valid is failing.
I'm not sure what I'm missing here however tried in different ways but couldn't resolve.

forms.py

```
class RelServiceForm2(forms.Form):
    ebsapp = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True)), label=_(""))
    code_version = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), label=_(""), required=False)
    mscv = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), label=_(""), required=False)
```

views.py

```
                mscv_versions_tup = []
                mscv_versions_tup = [('9.11.041', '9.11.041'), ('9.11.040', '9.11.040')]
                print('mscvversions', mscv_versions_tup)

                my_config = update_my_config(region='us-east-1', account='prod')
                client = session.client('elasticbeanstalk', config=my_config)

                _beanstalk_apps = _ebsstageapps.filter(ebsapp__type='beanstalk')
                _beanstalk_apps_list = list(_ebsstageapps.values_list('ebsapp__name', flat=True))

                print('_ebsstageapps : _beanstalk_apps', _beanstalk_apps_list)
                _response = client.describe_applications(ApplicationNames=_beanstalk_apps_list)['Applications']

                RelServiceFormSet = formset_factory(RelServiceForm2, extra=0, )
                formset = RelServiceFormSet(initial=[{'ebsapp': x} for x in _beanstalk_apps_list])

                for _beanstalk_app in _response:
                    code_versions = _beanstalk_app['Versions']
                    code_versions_tup = []
                    for v in code_versions:
                        code_versions_tup.append((v, v))
                    for form in formset:
                        if form['ebsapp'].value() == _beanstalk_app['ApplicationName']:
                            print(' Form sec Matched')
                            form.fields['code_version'].choices = code_versions_tup
                            form.fields['mscv'].choices = mscv_versions_tup
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    formset = RelServiceFormSet(request.POST,) # initial=[{'ebsapp': x} for x in _beanstalk_apps_list])

                    for _beanstalk_app in _response:
                        code_versions = _beanstalk_app['Versions']
                        code_versions_tup = []
                        for v in code_versions:
                            code_versions_tup.append((v, v))
                        for form in formset:
                            if form['ebsapp'].value() == _beanstalk_app['ApplicationName']:
                                form.fields['code_version'].choices = code_versions_tup
                                form.fields['mscv'].choices = mscv_versions_tup
                            else:
                                print('unmatched')
                    form = formset
                    print('print form before valid', form)
                    print('\n\n print')
     
                    if form.is_valid():
                        _release=Release.objects.create(name=datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y'), status='SUBMITTED')
                        print('It is valid form', form)
                        f = form.save(commit=False)
                        f.release = _release
                        f.save()
                        
                    else:
                        print('invalid FORM:', form)
                else:
                    form = formset
                    print(str(form))
```

template

```
{% if form %}
          <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
                       {{ form.management_form }}
{% for f in form %} {{f.as_table}}<br> {%endfor%}  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: Have you any "hidden" inputs in your html/CSS? I had a similar issues some time ago which was caused by a hidden radio button. Then the html validation already fails beforehand.

Comment: I haven't specified any hidden inputs but not sure if django it populating any hidden fields automatically. How do I check that and how to handle it?